# java.lang.classcastexception cannot be cast to in Java

Tags: java, jpa

I am trying to match and extract some employee entities from a table given some extensions as inputs however i can only get the results cast as Employee objects if i chain the query method like so :

```java
Employee x = em.createQuery("select e from Employee e where e.extension= 89667",Employee.class).getSingleResult();
```

If i try to put a placeholder then call the set Parameter function with a given extension i get an object array instead of my desired Employee class like so :

```
Query x = em.createQuery("select e from Employee e where e.extension=:ext", Employee.class);
    x.setParameter("ext",ext);
    Employee emp =  x.getSingleResult();
```

I would like to be able to get Employee objects as results as in the first example but dynamically setting the where clause as in the second , not sure if there is a simple way of doing so, I tried casting the result to the Employee Object but i get a casting error and if i were to map the resulting object array to a new Employee object it would become complicated in situations where the object is a mapped entity.

Comment: if you set the variable "ext" exactly to 89667, there should be no difference in the working of the two pieces of code. I presume you did not set the variable ext to the right value which might cause the system to return more than one record.
That always leads to an error if call getSingleResult. But ... That error would not be a classcastexception. So I think the second piece of code is not exactly right.

Comment: You code looks fine. Please post the code that don't work and also the full stacktrace

Comment: I ended up improvising . At the moment i dont have access to my stacktrace anymore, i took a risky  route by injecting the extension directly into the string then used the first approach. I figured its not much of a security risk as the extensions are being genarated internally. and it worked . I am using Java 8 by the way, incase that helps